# Add columns to pandas dataframe with no columns

Tags: pandas, dataframe, multiple-columns

I have a pandas dataframe with no headers- and i want to slice the row and add columns using "tokens" per row.

As an example:
if my df is like this

```
1 hilton   san Juan
2 Hyatt    mexico
3 Moon     Jamaica
------
```

I want to add column names based on position of strings in each row:
like

```
0-1 Number
3 -30 Hotel Name
31-60 City
```

How do i do it ?

Thanks, appreciate any inputs.

i tried using iloc - but without any columns, i couldnt use that.

Comment: Be more explicit on the output, give us an example

Comment: A DataFrame necessarily has a header/column names. By default, this is a numerical range (0, 1, 2...). What is the output of `df.columns`? And `df.head().to_dict()`? If you're describing format of the **file**, then use [`pandas.read_fwf`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_fwf.html).

Comment: thanks for the comments.. here is the output of df.head().to_dict(),

Comment: thanks for the comments.. here is the output of df.head().to_dict(),  `' 0        Hiton San Juan
1        Hyatt             Mexico           ...
...                                                    ...
1295985  Hyatt               SFO                ...
1295986  Hilton               San Jose                 ...
1295987  Sheraton           Miami                ...
1295988  Sheraton           NYC                       ...
[1295990 rows x 1 columns] `

Comment: Please share what you have tried so far.

Comment: My sample output should look like this:

No       Hotel Name       City
0        Hilton           San Juan
1        Hyatt            Mexico
------
1295985  Hyatt            SFO
Basically- i am trying to add columns to the df. I can only do that by using "positions". the character between position 3 an 30 in every row will be Hotel Name The character between position 31 and 60 will be city..

Please provide suggestions Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can add column names in the correct order as you want:

```
df.columns = ['Number', 'Hotel Name', 'City']
```